# HTML5 LocalStorage handling in different tabs

Tags: asp.net, html, local-storage

I am developing a website in asp.net in which I am developing user notes, for this purpose I have implemented notes in HTML5 and store the data in local storage and then save it into the database but the problem is this I have many user opened in different tabs and I want to show each user to his own notes so I can handle it with local storage?

Comment: Your question is quite confusing.  You talk about using local storage, but also talk about a database which typically implies storing on a server.  Where is the data actually stored?  When you say you have many different users opened, do you mean different users each on their own computer or do you mean many different users all opened in different tabs in the same browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see, in html5, local database store data in your browser.
so you can manage your database for particular browser.(like session and cookies)
Even if you open your page in different browser, you will not get your data that you have stored in last browser.
so if you want to store data for particular user in different browser then you can use inbuilt database of html5 otherwise you have to store your data on server side.